# Is there always a significant reward in the randomly generated dungeons?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far every randomly generated dungeon I have entered I have been rewarded with a golden chest at the end of the rainbow. Are there ever random dungeons (not including those one room dungeons) that have nothing at the end?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple - usually one-level dungeons - but even those tend to have Bloody Chests. Resplendent Chests appear seemingly without fail on optional dungeons with two floors.

Comment: I've seen two-floor dungeons without resplendent chests.

Answer (score 0):

Every single (non-quest-related) dungeon I have come across has had some sort of reward for going in, whether it be a chest, boss monsters loot, champion monsters loot, or treasure goblin (usually a combination of these) not to mention the exp, gold and regular loot off the dungeon monsters.

I'd say dungeons are definitely worth exploring, assuming they are near your character level.